# catkin clean does not clean cache for extend

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, running ROS Melodic.

*Here is what I did:*

In the terminal, I go to the location of my working space, where my current project, let us call it myRosProject, is located. I then build it with the command:

```
catkin build myRosProject
```

after it is completed successfully, I run the command:

```
catkin config
```

I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Your current environment's CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is different from the cached CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH used the last time this workspace was built.

If you want to use a different CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH you should call catkin clean to remove all references to the previous CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.
```

Indeed. The output of `catkin config`, in the field ***Extending***, is different from what is in my system variable $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. I should note here, that after ***Extending*** there is in green letters the text **[cached]**.

I then proceed to run `catkin clean`. After that, I build my project again (with the same command as above) and everything is done correctly. However, when I run `catkin config` again, I get the same warning.

So it seems that `catkin clean` did not do anything. I want my project to use the content of $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in the ***Extending*** field but I can't make it work. It continues to get the path from some cached memory, which I have no idea where it is located. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301735/catkin-clean-does-not-clean-cache-for-extend/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2018-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not entirely sure, but there is no "cache for extend" in `catkin_tools`.

That setting is part of the currently active profile, and is not affected by `catkin clean`. You'll have to change that using `catkin config --no-extend` (if you no longer wish to extend another workspace) or `catkin config --extend /path/to/the/workspace/to/extend` (if you wish to extend a different workspace).

> So it seems that `catkin clean` did not do anything.

I believe `catkin clean` did exactly what it was supposed to do, but you seem to want it to do something else.

> I want my project to use the content of $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in the ***Extending*** field but I can't make it work. It continues to get the path from some cached memory, which I have no idea where it is located. Any ideas?

If you can't do what you are after using `catkin config --extend ..` (to update the setting) then please clarify with some more detail what it is you want to do and perhaps we can help you.

---

Edit:

> I want to extend my work space to more the just one other.

That is specifically not supported (at least, not in the way you are trying to do it).

> When ever I used `catkin config --extend ...` I was able to only extend it to one other work space.

Yes, that is expected.

> For that reason, I was trying to use the $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable, which included multiple work spaces.

I'm not sure that will work, but note that to extend multiple workspaces, you'll have to layer them on-top of each other. You may already be familiar with it, but the technique is called [workspace overlaying](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying).

Workspace C overlays workspace B, which overlays workspace A. The union of all pkgs in workspaces A, B and C will be available after sourcing workspace C's `setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2018-08-28**:
@gvdhoorn I want to extend my work space to more the just one other. When ever I used `catkin config --extend ...` I was able to only extend it to one other work space. For that reason, I was trying to use the $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable, which included multiple work spaces.

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2018-08-28**:
@gvdhoorn The reason I tried to use $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable to extend to multiple work-spaces is because I read it in the [catkin documentation](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html#explicitly-specifying-workspace-chaining). Am I not understanding it correctly?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-28**:
If I interprete the docs correctly, it merely explains that `--extend` allows you to get `catkin` to ignore whatever the contents is of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or to override it with whatever you set `--extend` to. Passing `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `--extend` is not something I see documented there.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-28**:
Perhaps you can more clearly describe what you want to do, as I don't fully understand why regular workspace chaining / overlaying wouldn't work there.

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2018-08-31**:
@gvdhoorn I did not really try to do overlaying. I had 3 work spaces and wanted to have packages from these, to call each other. My understanding now is you can't just do it like that, with out applying chaining/overlaying.

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2018-08-31**:
@gvdhoorn I ended up just moving everything that I needed, in one work space. This makes sense because before I had some name conflicts as well. Thanks for helping me clear up things in my head.